# Identifying a toggle bar element text and clicking it in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test clicking on text which is part of a toggle bar to open its section.

The source code is something like this:

```
<h3 class="hdg hdg--3 hdg--muted">
Projects
<span class="toggleBar__toggle--icon toggleBar__icon--isOpen" data-ng-  class="{'toggleBar__icon--isOpen' : isVisible}"></span>
</h3>
```

The code is written in Javascript and I'm using this to test protractor:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('h3', 'Projects')).click();
```

When running my tests, I am getting the following error:

```
No element found using locator by.cssContainingText("h3", "Projects")
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try this:
element(by.cssContainingText('.hdg.hdg--3.hdg--muted', 'Projects')).click();

Comment: No, this didnt work. couldnt find element was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid, this is one of the cases where XPath is needed:

```
element(by.xpath("//h3[.//text()[normalize-space(.) = 'Projects']]")).click();
```

Or, if you need to click the `span` element inside:

```
element(by.xpath("//h3[.//text()[normalize-space(.) = 'Projects']]/span")).click();
```

---

> Both the commands work when i execute in debug mode. But, when i run it in normal, i get an error saying element not clickable at so and so point. Some other element accepts click.......

That means this is a timing issue. Add a wait:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.xpath("//h3[.//text()[normalize-space(.) = 'Projects']]"));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
elm.click();
```

Comment: Thank you. Both the commands work when i execute in debug mode. But, when i run it in normal, i get an error saying element not clickable at so and so point. Some other element accepts click.......

Comment: even after using this wait, i get the same error. then, i realized, when debugging, i used to manually scroll down to the bottom of the page as the element was not visible. so, i included a browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);'); command before the click command and it worked beautifully. Thanks for your earlier command on finding the element.